Extra items from freighter's mission not showing up in inventory
I received several valuable items from my last missions and I can't find them in any of my inventories. I thought they were added somewhere and went on with my adventure, until now.
I was selling some stuff at the market terminal and my freighter's inventory showed those items I thought I lost. I can only sell them, how the hell do I reach and recover them?

I realized that I now have a bugged tab in my frieghter (between CORE and STORAGE, the "diamond" one) which probably is containing all my lost stuff.
Any way to fix this mess?

Yes.
You can move items without accessing a specific inventory by hovering an empty slot and pressing  (or the relative button on other platforms) to bring items to that inventory from another one.
